# Android RCS Messages Broadcast Receiver Events and Content Provider

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

We are trying to develop an android application which can receive broadcast events of the RCS messages on all the devices. We are able to get the events on SAMSUNG Devices but not other brand mobile phones. Is there any event we can receive that can work on all mobiles phones.

Also we need the content provider url to read all the RCS Messages manually also.

We tried to receive events but not able to receive any events regarding RCS. Also tried to print all the content providers but not found any content provider which is related to RCS Messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think this is a particularly good question, specifically given that Android phones now often default to RCS and an SMS receiver won't even recognize the incoming message